# Get GitHub pull request number in VSTS build

Tags: github, sonarqube, azure-devops

Is it somehow possible to get the pull request number in a Visual Studio Team Service (vNext) build which is linked to a GitHub repository for builds run for pull requests?

I would like to do some code anylsis using sonar and write the finding back as comment to the pull request using [Sonar GitHub Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin).

Comment: So you want to get the pull request number that been built?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm looking for the GitHub pull request number.

Comment: Is the build queued every time the pull request is merged? Or the build may contain several pull requests?

Comment: I think I can set the build definition that it queues for each pull request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know any direct way to do this. The way I can think is add a PowerShell step to call "git log" command and read the information from the log. Since the commit information for pull request usually has a format like "Merge pull request #6 from XXX". We can use RegEx to get the pull request number.

```
git log -1 >log.txt
$file = Get-Content log.txt
$reg = "Merge.pull.request.+(?<pullnumber>\w+?).from+"
foreach($line in $file){
    if($line -match $reg){        
        $Matches.pullnumber;
    }
 }
```